# (React) Margin auto not working for my pagination bar

Tags: css, reactjs

I am a beginner in Web Development.
Why can't I place the pagination bar to be horizontally centered?
I have tried to include width:100% and even display: block.
However, results are the same.
Thank you for your help.

[image: Current Layout]

I want to put the pagination in the center of the red border.

App.js

```
 ...   
 <Pagination postsPerPage={imagePerPage} totalPosts={totalImages} paginate= {paginate}/>
 ...
```

Pagination.js

```
import React , { useState, useRef, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const Pagination = ({ postsPerPage, totalPosts, paginate }) => {
const pageNumbers = [];
const [currentPage,setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalPosts / postsPerPage); i++) {
  pageNumbers.push(i);
}

const totalNumOfPages = pageNumbers.length;

useEffect(() => {
console.log("Cureent Page:")
console.log(currentPage);

},[currentPage]);

return (
<nav>
  <ul className='pagination' style={{width:'100%',margin:'auto',border: '1px solid red' }}>
      <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" aria-label="Previous"
         onClick={() =>{ 
          if (currentPage > 1){
          paginate(currentPage-1);
          setCurrentPage(currentPage-1);
          }
          }
        } 
      >
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    {pageNumbers.map(number => (
    
      <li key={number} 
          className={ `page-item ${(currentPage === number)? 'active' : '' }`}>
        <a onClick={() =>{ paginate(number);setCurrentPage(number)}} className='page-link' >
          {number}
        </a>
      </li>
    ))}
     <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link"  aria-label="Next" 
                onClick={() =>{ 
                  if (currentPage < totalNumOfPages){
                    paginate(currentPage+1);
                    setCurrentPage(currentPage+1);
                  }
                  }
                } 
          >
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
);
};

export default Pagination;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using Bootstrap. `.pagination` is configured to be a [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) container. This is why your `li` elements are already displayed in a row. You can still use the concept of `auto` margins, but instead of doing it on the parent, you can use this property on the children.

```
li.page-item:first-child {
    margin-left: auto;
}

li.page-item:last-child {
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to put your elements into div as below, and move the ul style part to a separate div.

```
<div className="text-center">
  <div style={{width:'100%', border: '1px solid red', height : '40px'}}>
   <nav>
    <ul className='pagination' >
    ....
```

Second, override pagination class with

```
.pagination {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

Here is the [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pagination-center-opv3c).